# How can I count in a different number base in C++?

Tags: c++, count, numbers

My 15 year old little brother is starting out programming, and he wrote a neat little program that outputs all combination of letters and numbers that are six digits or less.  His code was a sextuple-nested for loop that updated the elements of a six level char array.  It looked bad, but was certainly fast!  I showed him how to do a simple count, and convert those numbers to base 36.

The biggest problem is that my code was so much slower than his, due to the division I was doing.  Is there a way that I can simply assume base 36 and output a count from 1 to 36^6?

Ideally, I'm looking to do something like

```
[base 36]
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
   SaveForLaterFileOutput(i);
```

Comment: You are confusing value with presentation.  Pure counting is not a concept that can be given a radix.  A refactored version your brother's solution might be the better of the two!

Comment: There is no built-in base36 construct in the language. However, you don't need division to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char buffer[1024];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      cout << itoa ( i, buffer, 36);
```

<s>Here it is without itoa (if you don't have it)</s>

```
cout << setbase (36);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      cout << i << endl;
cout << setbase (10); // if you intend to keep using cout
```

Comment: `itoa` isn’t in the standard and not all C++ libraries include it.

Comment: Updated to have an answer without itoa (thanks @Konrad Rudolph)

Comment: I thought setbase() could only be used with base-8, -10 and -16?

Comment: the second version is more idiomatic, regardless of whether you have itoa() or not.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for your brother to update his 6-element array without needing 6 nested loops. By modifying the `increment` function below, you can count in any "base" you choose:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#define NUM_CHARS 6

// assuming ASCII
// advances through a chosen sequence 0 .. 9, a .. z
// or returns -1 on overflow
char increment(char &c) {
    if (c == 'z') return -1;
    if (c == '9') { c = 'a'; return c; }
    return ++c;
}

int main() {
    char source[NUM_CHARS+1] = {0};
    std::fill_n(&source[0], NUM_CHARS, '0');
    while (true) {
        std::cout << source << "\n";
        int idx = NUM_CHARS;
        // increment and test for overflow
        while (increment(source[--idx]) == -1) {
            // overflow occurred: carry the 1
            source[idx] = '0';
            if (idx == 0) return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't bothered with the "or fewer" part of the problem: however you've done it with 6 loops will probably work with this technique too. Strictly speaking, this is enumerating combinations, which is nearly but not quite the same thing as counting.

Answer (score 1):

to convert a number to base 36: make an accumulator and start from a sufficiently high degree, for example 36^6.  If accumulator plus that number is less than your number, add it to the accumulator and repeat for the same degree (the count of this is the digit value), if it's greater, throw it away.  Repeat for lower degrees until you get to 36^0.  Keep track of the count for each degree, and that's your number in base 36.

to print it out in a meaningful way, do something else.

Answer (score 1):

All numbers used in calculations are in base 2.  Any other number you see is just an illusion on how it's printed.  Hence your `SaveForLaterOutput` is pointless.

The library function `itoa()` (that translates to "integer to ASCII") (these days it has been replaced by the secure `_itoa_s()` function) allows you to specify the base when preparing for output.

Comment: There is no such thing as "2" in binary, so technically, all calculations are in base 10 binary (not to be confused with the number ten we humans like so much).

Comment: There are only 10 kinds of people in the world: Those who understand binary & those who don't.

Comment: There are 10 kinds of people: those who understand ternary, those who don't and those who mistake it for binary;)

Comment: ...and those who make lame overused jokes without specifying the base and magically expect us to know what they're talking about.

Comment: All numbers used in calculations are *numbers*. Any base that they may be physically represented in while being operated on, is an implementation detail (and with modern CPUs it isn't necessarily so simple as an int register actually being 32 little wires, each of which either carries a current or doesn't). In memory they are all but required to be represented in something approximating to base UCHAR_MAX+1, whereas the existence of the bitwise operators means that a binary internal representation is a natural way to imagine them.

Comment: Still, your basic point is spot on, that there's no such thing as "a base 10 number", just "a base 10 representation of a number".